# Html menu with jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish that when I modify an item in a drop down menu jquery change the html file that was produced by a php script.
This is the code:

**JQUERY**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#regioni').change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == 'Home') {
                $('.classtesto').show();
                $('.classfile').hide();
                $('.classfoto').hide();
                $('.classlogo').hide();
                $('.classcategoria').hide();
            }
            if ($(this).val() == 'Gallery') {
                $('.classtesto').hide();
                $('.classfile').hide();
                $('.classfoto').show();
                $('.classlogo').show();
                $('.classcategoria').show();
            }
            if ($(this).val() == 'News') {
                $('.classtesto').show();
                $('.classfile').show();
                $('.classfoto').show();
                $('.classlogo').hide();
                $('.classcategoria').hide();
            }
            if ($(this).val() == 'Risultati') {
                $('.classtesto').show();
                $('.classfile').hide();
                $('.classfoto').show();
                $('.classlogo').hide();
                $('.classcategoria').show();
            }
            if ($(this).val() == 'Sponsor') {
                $('.classtesto').show();
                $('.classfile').hide();
                $('.classfoto').hide();
                $('.classlogo').show();
                $('.classcategoria').hide();
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
            <select name="regione" id="regioni">
                <option value="">Selezionane una</option>
                <?php foreach ($regioni as $regione): ?>
                    <option value="<?php htmlout($regione); ?>"<?php
                    if ($regione == $nome_regione) {
                        echo ' selected="selected"';
                    }
                    ?>><?php htmlout($regione); ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
```

I have 2 problems:

**1**.When I click on the "choose an item" the program does not work (it does not hide tags);

**2**.When php code sets a menu item of the page, the program does not work (it does not hide tags).

Unfortunately no expert on jquery and javascript so I can not find a solution for this problem relatively simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need an IF statement for when "select one" is selected.
2. You need to call .change() after finish loading options from php.

   if ($(this).val() == '') {
   $('.classtesto').hide();
   $('.classfile').hide();
   $('.classfoto').hide();
   $('.classlogo').hide();
   $('.classcategoria').hide();
   }

After the select html code (make sure it goes after the dropdown):

```
$('#regioni').change();
```

Also, you'd have to change the trigger to:

```
$('#regioni').on('change', function () {
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PTyT7/)

Comment: 1.If I add if ($(this).val() == '') it works, thanks!


2.If I add ...</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#regioni').change(); 
</script> the script doesnìt work... :(

1.Ok :)

2.No :(

Comment: Make sure the .change() is after the selct. I have updated my answer with link to jsfiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/PTyT7/)

Comment: The example I provided in JSfiddle works. Also NOTE: the trigger is changed to $('#regioni').on('change', function (){}

Comment: If I try your example of a file without php it works, but when the page is dynamic does not work. : (

Comment: Yes I used $('#regioni').on('change', function (){} too

Comment: I put the code before the </ body> or after the last php function so your code works well, thanks! :)